# Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'splice'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem in passing an array to a function in JavaScript.

I have a Room with walls that has to be saved, but there are too many elements so i split them in parts. When u click on "save" this is the first function that is called:

```
function getCompleteParamlist(id)
{
var paramlist = $("#edit_form_"+id).serialize();
var params = paramlist.split("&");

var id                      = params[0];
var name                    = params[1];
var x_max                   = params[2];
var y_max                   = params[3];
var tools                   = params[4];
var style_toolbrush         = params[5];
var roompiece_brushchooser  = params[6];
params.splice(0,7);
var y = y_max.replace(/\D/g, '');
var length = params.length;

var fixed_params = id+"&"+name+"&"+x_max+"&"+y_max+"&"+tools+"&"+style_toolbrush+"&"+roompiece_brushchooser+"&y_val=";

prepareSaveRoom(fixed_params,params,y,length,1);
}
```

It gets all the values that are going to be saved, splits them into an array and builds an a string of params used every time. Removed the already used parameters and calls the next function:

```
function prepareSaveRoom(fixed_params,params,loops,length,count)
{
    var temp_paramlist  = fixed_params+count;

for(var i=1; i<=length/loops; i++)
{
    temp_paramlist += "&"+params[0];
    params.splice(0,1);
}

if (count == loops)
{
    temp_paramlist += "&last=true";
    saveRoom(temp_paramlist,1,fixed_params,params,loops,length,count);
}
else
{
    temp_paramlist += "&last=false";
    count++;
    saveRoom(temp_paramlist,0,fixed_params,params,loops,length,count);
}
}
```

This works on the first run and the new temporary parameterlist is build and the saveRoom function is called. This builds a partial parameterlist that is going to be saved. removed the objects from the array and calls the save funvtion

```
function saveRoom(temp_paramlist,lastloop,fixed_params,params,loops,length,count)
{
alert(temp_paramlist);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "SaveRoom?"+temp_paramlist,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        if(lastloop == 1){
            location.href=data;
        }
        else{
            window.setTimeout("prepareSaveRoom('"+fixed_params+"','"+params+"','"+loops+"','"+length+"','"+count+"')",2000);
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        showErrorDialogHandleSecondDiv(data.responseText,"#edit_room");
    }
}); 
}
```

This method calls a Java Controller which saves the values and then it calls the prepareSaveRoom function again, until all parameters are handled. But when saveRoom() calls prepareSaveRoom and it gets to the point:

```
for(var i=1; i<=length/loops; i++)
{
    temp_paramlist += "&"+params[0];
    params.splice(0,1);
}
```

I get the error that the Object has no method 'splice'.
I can't find the bug and so I'm trying to find some help here.
i don't know why i can't call splice on the parameter array that is passed from function to function.

Thanks for reading and possible help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting everything into a string. In fact, you've explicitly enclosed `params` with quotes as if you wanted it to be a string:

```
window.setTimeout("prepareSaveRoom('"+fixed_params+"','"+params+"','"+loops+"','"+length+"','"+count+"')",2000);
```

Strings do not have `.splice`. You want to pass the array `params`, not a string representation of it.

Another reason *not* to pass a string to `setTimeout`. You should pass a function at all times:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    prepareSaveRoom(fixed_params, params, loops, length, count);
}, 2000);
```

That way, you indeed pass an array (so no string conversion).

Comment: this worked perfectly. i don't know why i did not try this. myabe to long in front of the code. thank you very much. will accept this answer as soon as i can. have a 7 min timeout.

Answer (score 1):

pimvdb looks to have hit the nail on the head, but I'll post this for general info anyway, because I've already written it :)

---

You can't call `splice` because it's not an array. Use `console.log(typeof params)` to find out what it is, and start backtracking through your code to see why it's not an array.

Possible contenders
 - The selector `#edit_form_ + id` should be `#edit_form + id`
 - The `id` param being passed in doesn't match the ID of the form
 - The form is empty, so serializing does nothing

Comment: thanks for the answer and the infos. as i mentioned in the OP the first run was succesfull so the id and the serializing worked. after that the first function is never called again, so this could not be the source of the failure. i love stackoverflow and you guys. you helped my already so many times.